# Need help regarding very basic issue about .Net program execution flow and basic oops related

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Doubt about .net program execution flow

for few year i am working as a develop but i have lack of knowledge for how C# win or web apps run. when we run application from IDE then how compiler come into scene to compile our program and after then how program start....how CLR come into scene and how JIT come into scene. who take control over the entry point of program. who invoke program entry point so called static void Main() from outside like. how CLR involve to take the responsibility for executing the program & Who involve the CLR. how JIT involve and who involve the JIT. why the entry point is static void main() ?

lot of book help us to write code with C# but never talk about the program execution flow....how a .net program is running. when we click on any .net exe then how exe is getting run. so i have some doubt....if possible then please discuss the above issue in detail or point me towards right article.

Doubt about OOPS

1) i saw a class which was private but constructor was public....why...what does it mean. is there any special purpose that is why class is designed like this.

2) i saw public class but it has three constructor one was private, one was static and last one was public......is there any special purpose to design a class in this way.

3) static class always have static constructor?

4) if a public class has normal constructor along with static constructor then what will be the purpose.

if possible then please discuss the above OOPS issue in details........thanks

Comment: Ask _one_ question that can be answered, don't start discussions on SO.

Comment: As @TimSchmelter said, please don't ask about multiple things in a single question.

Comment: for one year i am working as developer....so i can ask very basic question. so what is wrong with basic question. why i am getting huge negative mark.......if people do not like my question then they can leave aside...isn't.

Comment: @KeithCosta: You're getting downvotes because you have asked *several questions* within the same SO question. You need to ask *one* question per SO question.

Comment: @KeithCosta: It's not closed because the question is too basic but because you're asking multiple questions at once. Even if you would split it into multiples it cannot be answered (correctly) since it's subjective, argumentative and too broad. Have a look at the FAQ what can be asked on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/faq  **"Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when we run application from IDE then how compiler come into scene to compile our program

The IDE starts the compiler and passes it your program. The compiler is another program. It doesn't need special invocation. You can do it yourself without an IDE by just calling `csc.exe` directly.

> and after then how program start....how CLR come into scene and how JIT come into scene. who take control over the entry point of program. who invoke program entry point so called static void Main() from outside like. how CLR involve to take the responsibility for executing the program & Who involve the CLR. how JIT involve and who involve the JIT.

The JIT is the dynamic IL-to-native compiler. It's what translates the IL that .NET languages are compiled into so that the programs can actually run.

The CLR is pretty much another world for the JIT in the way you're using it. I'm not going to go into detail here, but you can find out more on MSDN.

> why the entry point is static void main() ?

Convention. Why is the language called C#?

> i saw a class which was private but constructor was public....why...what does it mean. is there any special purpose that is why class is designed like this.

It's so that the private class can be instantiated from the outer class. For example:

```
public class A {
    private something = new B();

    private class B {
        public B() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

If the constructor weren't `public`, the `private` class could not be instantiated by the outer class.

> i saw public class but it has three constructor one was private, one was static and last one was public......is there any special purpose to design a class in this way.

Sure. They all do different things. It's not so unusual.

> static class always have static constructor?

No. Static constructors are actually very rare. Of course, a static class cannot have a normal constructor.

> if a public class has normal constructor along with static constructor then what will be the purpose.

The normal constructor is called to initialize an object. The static constructor is called the first time the class is used. Just because a class has both doesn't make it special, you could use that functionality for just about anything.

Comment: i got no answer how a .net application execute when we run our program from IDE or just double clicking on application exe file. lot of scholar person is there they can easily drive out my confusion. please help......thanks

Comment: thanks for ur answer but u did not say like after compilation how JIT comes into scene. who will call JIT to convert IL to native code. how exe or assembly file will be running. who involve CLR to execute or running the exe or assembly. looking for ur answer....thanks

Comment: @KeithCosta: The EXE itself invokes the CLR. That's what's at the beginning of a .NET EXE - code to tell the CLR to run the rest of the program.