# Some basic questions about JIT-Compiler and installation

Tags: .net, compilation, installation, jit

I am reading about .NET at the moment and some basic questions came into my mind. I am asking these questins to be sure I've understood things right since I am preparing for a presentation.

When I open an exe-file on my computer it is handled by the CLR to get compiled. A JIT-Compiler exectutes MSIL code "Just-In-Time" so that only the needed parts are compiled at runtime. Now this compiled pieces will be stored in memory for later access.

First question:

> What part does the installation process e.g. through an install
>   wizzard play here? Or is istallation just needed in directly compiled
>   scenarios where the compiler first has to go through all of the code
>   before runtime? That means that installing the program is basicaly
>   compiling it on a production machine, right?

Second question:

> Is the JIT-compiled code stored in harddrive so that compiled code
>   never is compiled again or is this compilation process done everytime
>   I click on an exe-file?

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316757/need-help-regarding-very-basic-issue-about-net-program-execution-flow-and-basic

Comment: @akfkmupiwu I am sorry but how is that one a possible duplicate? I already know about the execution flow. My question is just about clarifieng confusion I have regarding installation and jit-compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **3 JIT compilers** and even the new [RyuJIT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/30/ryujit-the-next-generation-jit-compiler.aspx).

**Pre-JIT** :compiles complete source code into **native code** in a single compilation cycle. This is done at the time of deployment of the application.

**Econo-JIT** :compiles only those methods that are called at runtime. However, these compiled methods are removed when they are not required.

**Normal JIT** :Normal-JIT compiles only those methods that are called at runtime. These methods are compiled the first time they are called, and then they are stored in cache. When the same methods are called again, the compiled code from cache is used for execution.

Above should answer "**JIT-compiled code stored in harddrive so that compiled code never is compiled again**"

**There are multiple types of application like winform, asp.net web based, asp.net MVC, Window Service, class library and so on...** There deployment (Installation) will also vary.  Some of the deployment method is MSI, Setup, manual copy, x-copy, and ClickOnce etc.

**Now we talk about different types of Installers;**

**MSI**: An MSI is a Windows Installer database. Windows Installer program utilise this database to install software on our system. **What does this installation mean, I believe this is your first question**?.

**Setup.exe**: A setup program may extract the required files from itself and will handle the installation process. Or this can call an MSI to install. **What does this installation mean, I believe this completes your question**

Now in my view output of installation from MSI/Setup is the MSIL in all cases and then JIT comes into picture at runtime. The MSIL can contain manifest, metadata and resources. Resources can also have machine-executable code. It is a case of assembly that runs an unmanaged program, which is embedded in to assembly.